# username.github.io is not updating

Tags: windows, git, github

Github rookie here.

I am trying to update my personal site but after many adds (git add . and git add )and commits and push (git push/ git push origin master), nothing changed. The commits seem to work tho.  I tried the git config http.postBuffer 524288000 method because I was getting the fatal error every time I used git push. That went away but the site hasn't changed at all. I know it takes a while to change but it's been 7 hours. :/
And the sync button isn't working too.

Let me know if you guys need more details on this.

Comment: There is likely an error message when trying to build your page. Go to your repository on Github, then "Settings" on the right, and scroll down to the "Github Pages" section. If there's an error, it should be listed there.

Comment: Scrolled down to the section, but I saw no error message.

Comment: Are you sure that you are committing and pushing to the correct branch? [User and Organization pages should use `master`](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages) and [Project pages should use `gh-pages`](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages).

Comment: I believe I am using the correct branch. Since I'm trying to create a personal site so I'm using master. I only have some html, css and other files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what it was and hopefully, it'll help those who are facing the same problem as I did.

So the reason why I wasn't able to sync and update my site was because of the CSS folder that I had (makes me want to smack myself). So what I did was I took out all the stylesheets and deleted the CSS folder. Then I undid all the recent changes from Github (under the Gear icon on the left side-->Undo most recent commit) and from there I was about to sync them.  Just make sure to fix up your html files since those stylesheets were moved.